# how to select xml element based on it attribute value start with "somthing" in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, xml-parsing

say, I have an xml like as follows:

```
public static var keywords:XML = <keywords>
   <tag key="html" type="tag"/>
   <tag key="htmlNew" type="attr"/>
   <tag key="head" type="attr"/>
   <tag key="body" type="attr"/>
</keywords>;
```

I need to search this xml by attribute value. If user provides input as "html" then I need to return both `<tag key="html" type="tag"/> <tag key="htmlNew" type="attr"/>` node as XMLList. It kind of start with type searching by xml attribute. Please anybody provide any kind of solution or suggestion. for direct attribute matching I have used following code:

```
var closeMatchList:XMLList = xml.tag.(@key == "html") as XMLList;
```

It returns only `<tag key="html" type="tag"/>` tag

Is this kind of solution is possible?? please anybody provide any kind of solution. I am stuck with this problem for long time. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Without third party libraries you could also do this:

```
keywords.tag.(attribute("key").indexOf("html")==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an XPath library for ActionScript3 ([xpath-as3](http://code.google.com/p/xpath-as3/)) that can do this easily.

```
public static var keywords:XML = ...;

var thePath:String = "/keywords/tag[starts-with(@key, 'html')]";
var html:NodeSet = XPath.evaluate(thePath, keywords);
```

Some other ways to use the library can be seen [over here](http://lab.arc90.com/2010/04/28/actionscript-3-xpath-library/).